# I am trying to implement shadow effect on button using react native but did not work can any one help me?

Tags: react-native

FlatButton class

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

export default class FlatButton extends Component {
  state = {
    backgroundColor: "#f01d71",
    backgroundColor2: "#f01d71",
    pressed: false,
  };

  changeColor() {
    if (!this.state.pressed) {
      this.setState({
        pressed: true,
        backgroundColor: "rgb(60,32,140)",
        backgroundColor2: "#f01d71",
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        pressed: false,
        backgroundColor: "#f01d71",
        backgroundColor2: "#f01d71",
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor,
            borderRadius: 10,
            padding: 10,
            shadowColor: "#000000",
            shadowOffset: {
              width: 0,
              height: 3,
            },
            shadowRadius: 5,
            shadowOpacity: 1.0,
          }}
          onPress={() => this.changeColor()}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.text}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: "white",
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 16,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Second component where I am rendering the `FlatButton`

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import FlatButton from "../shared/FlatButton";
const CustomizationView = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.btnflex}>
        <FlatButton text="Crop" />
        <FlatButton text="Crop" />
        <FlatButton text="Crop" />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.btnflex}>
        <FlatButton text="Crop" />
        <FlatButton text="Crop" />
        <FlatButton text="Crop" />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    // borderWidth : 5,
    // borderColor : 'black',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  btnflex: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: 5,
    padding: 5,
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderColor: "red",
  },
});

export default CustomizationView;
```

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B9q5.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this package. You can add different types of shadows and create an amazing UI.

```
react-native-neomorph-shadows
```

Here is the example
[link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tokkozhin/react-native-neomorph-shadows/master/assets/shadows.gif).

[Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-neomorph-shadows) to the library.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to the answers provided above , i usually find using this online shadow generator an easy way to get the desired results for android and ios

https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/

Answer (score 1):

use elevation property also

```
        <View style={{

            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            padding:5
            }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
            backgroundColor:'#ff0000', 
            borderRadius: 10,
            padding: 10,
            shadowColor: '#000000',
            shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 3
            },
            shadowRadius: 10,
            shadowOpacity: 1.0,
            elevation: 5,
            }}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{"new button"}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

In react-native, shadowColor, shadowOffset, shadowOpacity and shadowRadius properties are used for shadow in iOS. Whereas in android, you only need to pass elevation property. Make sure to add backgroundColor. Here is an example:

```
shadowColor: "#000",
shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 2,
},
shadowOpacity: 0.25,
shadowRadius: 3.84,

elevation: 5,
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use "Elevation: 4" for use shadow in react native. hope this code can help your problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the property:

```
backgroundColor: 'some color here'
```

If you don't pass the shadow will not work properly.

Try this on your TouchableOpacity style:

```
style={{
    backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor || '#fff', 
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10,
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 3
    },
    shadowRadius: 5,
    shadowOpacity: 1.0
    }}
```

when you use the || the background of your button will always be white in case you don't pass the parameter this.state.backgroundColor, as you did here when you called your component.

```
 <FlatButton text="Crop" />
```

Comment: in android the only way to add shadow is the elevation.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but if you dont pass the backgroundColor it does not work